# Grep running within a piped ProcessBuilder never terminates

Tags: java, linux, shell

I am trying to implement a shell in java, and as part of the requirements I can only use the ProcessBuilder class to redirect IO.  Threads or polling of process IO streams is not allowed.  I have everything working fine, however I can't seem to get pipes (|) to work properly.  The way I am currently implementing them is by creating a different ProcessBuilder for each sub-command, and then setting the input of each to the output of the one before it, with the head and tail of the pipe linked to the shell's inherited IO streams.  This works fine but some processes (particularly grep) do not terminate and never output anything when used in this way.  Grep works fine without pipes (grep -i  ), but when run in the pipe (ls | grep txt) it never terminates despite ls having already finished (this is verifiable by checking the process tree of the shell).

I understand that the normal solution is to just poll each process's IO streams and copy bytes as they come in, or to create a wrapper class that creates a thread to do this for you.  Unfortunately I am not allowed to use either method for this assignment, so I am stuck with ProcessBuilder.

Googling has gotten me nowhere, so any help would be appreciated!  Here is the relevant code:

```
/*
  Runs a pipeline of commands.  Each String argument is a command to execute and pipe to the next.
*/
private static void runExternalMulti(String[] cmds) {
    //array of process builders in order of pipe
    ProcessBuilder[] builders = new ProcessBuilder[cmds.length];
    for (String cmd : cmds) {
        cmd = cmd.trim();
        for (int i = 0; i < builders.length; i++) {
            builders[i] = createProcessBuilder(cmd.split("\\s+"));
        }
    }

    //set ProcessBuilder pipes
    //skip last index
    for (int i = 0; i < builders.length - 1; i++) {
        ProcessBuilder first = builders[i];
        ProcessBuilder next = builders[i+1];
        first.redirectOutput(next.redirectInput());
        next.redirectInput(first.redirectOutput());
    }

    //start each process and hold in array
    Process[] processes = new Process[builders.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < builders.length; i++) {
        processes[i] = builders[i].start();
    }

    //loop until all process have finished
    boolean running = true;
    while (running) {
        running = false;
        for (Process process : processes) {
            if (process.isAlive()) {
                running = true;
            }
        }
        //pause to avoid churning CPU
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
}

/*
  Creates a processBuilder for the command specified in parts.  Each string is a space-separated part of the command line, with the first being the executable to run.
*/
private static ProcessBuilder createProcessBuilder(String[] parts) {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
    builder.directory(currentDirectory);  //set working directory
    //set process to share IO streams with java shell
    builder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
    builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
    builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

    //parse each token and pull out IO redirection and background characters
    List<String> command = new ArrayList<>(parts.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        //Ignore the background character, it has been read or ignored by the calling function
        if (i == parts.length - 1 && "&".equals(parts[i])) {
            continue; //don't parse an ending "&" as a command parameter
        }
        String str = parts[i];
        //redirect to a file
        if (">".equals(str)) {
            if (i < parts.length - 1) {
                File outFile = new File(currentDirectory, parts[i + 1]);
                builder.redirectOutput(outFile);
                builder.redirectError(outFile);
            }
            i++; //make sure to skip the redirected file name
        //read in from a file
        } else if ("<".equals(str)) {
            if (i < parts.length - 1) {
                File inFile = new File(currentDirectory, parts[i + 1]);
                if (inFile.isFile()) {
                    builder.redirectInput(inFile);
                }
            }
            i++; //make sure to skip the redirected file name
        } else {
            command.add(parts[i]);
        }
    }
    builder.command(command);
    return builder;
}
```

Comment: As you have probably guessed, redirectInput() and redirectOutput() do not return connectable pipes.  They just return objects describing how input/output is being redirected.  If you are not allowed to use Process.getInputStream() and Process.getOutputStream(), I cannot think of any alternative except redirecting the source process’s output to a file, and then having the receiving process redirect its input from that file.  Which means the two pipe-connected processes won’t be able to run concurrently at all.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected this was the case but I couldn't find anything else that could possibly work.  This is just extra credit so I'll skip it and ask my professor about it.  The assignment is new this year so I guess no one ever actually checked to make sure it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe is feature of command line interpreter. So you have to options:

1. wrap commands with pipes into `bash -c` (so you'll have command `bash` with 2 arguments)
2. split commands by pipes, read stdout of one line by line and send it to stdin of second.

If I understand correctly you cannot use latter, but maybe first is allowed?

Comment: I've actually implemented the second method already, but I'm only allowed to use ProcessBuilder methods to connect the process.  Apparently that isnt possible, but this is just extra credit so I'll ask my professor if there is supposed to be an exception for this part.